# KeyError in text generator

Tags: python, random, keyerror

I'm trying to write code that will collect statistics on the sequence of characters in the text and generate new text based on it. This works when collecting statistics with one character, but as soon as I try to increase the number of characters, I get KeyError:

```
import zipfile
from random import randint
from pprint import pprint


# file_zip = 'voyna-i-mir.txt.zip'

# zip = zipfile.ZipFile(file_zip, 'r')
# for file in zip.namelist():
#     zip.extract(file)

origin = 'voyna-i-mir.txt'

statistic = {}

chain = '   '
with open(origin, 'r', encoding='cp1251') as file:
    for sting in file:
        #print(sting)
        for symbol in sting:
            if chain in statistic:
                if symbol in statistic[chain]:
                    statistic[chain][symbol] += 1
                else:
                    statistic[chain][symbol] = 1
            else:
                statistic[chain] = {symbol: 1}
            chain = chain[1:] + symbol


dictionary = {}
stat_generator = {}
for chain, symbol_stat in statistic.items():
    dictionary[chain] = 0
    stat_generator[chain] = []
    for symbol, count in symbol_stat.items():
        dictionary[chain] += count
        stat_generator[chain].append([count, symbol])
    stat_generator[chain].sort(reverse=True)

gen = 1000
was_print = 0

chain = '   '
while was_print < gen:
    symbol_stat = stat_generator[chain]
    total = dictionary[chain]
    random = randint(1, total)
    position = 0
    for count, symbol in symbol_stat:
        position += count
        if random <= position:
            break
        print(symbol, end='')
        was_print += 1
        chain = chain[1:] + symbol
```

The error I received

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\roman\Desktop\skillbox\[Skillbox] Профессия Python- 
разработчик\9. Работа с файлами и форматированный 
вывод-20210102T191733Z-001\9. Работа с файлами и форматированный 
вывод\lesson_009\python_snippets\test.py", line 46, in <module>
    symbol_stat = stat_generator[chain]
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
KeyError: ' -–'
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: line 46, in <module>
    symbol_stat = stat_generator[chain]
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
KeyError: ' -–'

Comment: Add it to the question ad code-formatted text. And make sure it is complete.

Comment: I added an error to the question, but it is not entered in the code format.

Comment: Why do you have two duplicates  `chain = '   '`?

Comment: What if you comment out line 44?

Comment: I have eternal input, after i break Run, have this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roman\Desktop\skillbox\[Skillbox] Профессия Python-разработчик\9. Работа с файлами и форматированный вывод-20210102T191733Z-001\9. Работа с файлами и форматированный вывод\lesson_009\python_snippets\test.py", line 45, in <module>
    while was_print < gen:
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Apparently when you do `chain = chain[1:] + symbol` you're creating a value for `chain` that isn't a key of `stat_generator`